# Are inequalities harder to prove than equalities?

Tags: inequality, soft-question

Browsing through the [inequalities](/questions/tagged/inequalities) tag, I see a lot of straightforward-looking arithmetic statements that I nevertheless have no idea how to prove ([and apparently I'm not alone](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inequality?sort=unanswered)). With equalities it's usually clear what is required: A sequence of clever arithmetic manipulations until at last one arrives at a tautology. With inequalities, I often find myself not even knowing where to start.

Is this true in general, or do I simply not know the right techniques to apply here?

Comment: It probably depends which apple you compare with which pear. To prove that $n! \ge n^2 $ for $n \ge 4$ is fairly straightforward. To prove that the number of colours required to colour a map so that all adjacent countries (and the sea) are different is equal to 4 took a computer.

Comment: @TomCollinge: I'm interested in purely arithmetic statements. Your second example is not purely arithmetic.

Comment: Let N be the minimum number of colours required; prove N = 4.

Comment: Note that for real numbers, any inequality is equivalent to some equality and any equality is equivalent to some inequality, at least if you include identities containing square roots: $a\le b$ iff $a=b-\sqrt{(b-a)^2}$ and $a=b$ iff $(b-a)^2\le0$. Just to say that the question should be made more precise, even if there is some truth in it.